# count html radio buttons value with php

Tags: php, html

I have a html form with grouped radio button. This form contains questions with yes or no options

```
<form action="results.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"><br>
            <p>Have you ever turned a client down?</p>
            <div id="q_1">
                <input type="radio" name="q[]" id="q_1_yes" value="yes">
                <label for="q_1_yes">Yes</label>
                <input type="radio" name="q[]" id="q_1_no" value="no">
                <label for="q_1_no">No</label>
            </div><br>
            <p>Are you comfortable with failure?</p>
            <div id="q_1">
                <input type="radio" name="q[]" id="q_2_yes" value="yes">
                <label for="q_2_yes">Yes</label>
                <input type="radio" name="q[]" id="q_2_no" value="no">
                <label for="q_2_no">No</label>
            </div><br>
            <p>Can your concept be easily described and understood?</p>
            <div id="q_1">
                <input type="radio" name="q[]" id="q_3_yes" value="yes">
                <label for="q_3_yes">Yes</label>
                <input type="radio" name="q[]" id="q_3_no" value="no">
                <label for="q_3_no">No</label>
            </div><br>
                    <input type="submit" name="sub_eit" id="sub_eit" value="Submit">
                </div>
            </form>
```

I know i can count the number of radio buttons with name q

```
$count_cbox = count($_POST['q'])
```

But is it possible that when the user makes a choice i count the radio button value that ="yes" or "no".

Comment: iterate over `$_POST` and count how often `yes` is found then work with `switch(yesCount){case 1: /*any code*/ break; case 2: /* any code*/ break;}`

Comment: You can use some count variable or store the result in array.

Comment: btw it's `recommend` not `recomend`

Answer (score 0):

Please change your radio button names slightly. Otherwise the grouping doesn't work:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"><br>
<p>Have you ever turned a client down?</p>
<div id="q_1">
    <input type="radio" name="q[0]" id="q_1_yes" value="yes">
    <label for="q_1_yes">Yes</label>
    <input type="radio" name="q[0]" id="q_1_no" value="no">
    <label for="q_1_no">No</label>
</div><br>
<p>Are you comfortable with failure?</p>
<div id="q_1">
    <input type="radio" name="q[1]" id="q_2_yes" value="yes">
    <label for="q_2_yes">Yes</label>
    <input type="radio" name="q[1]" id="q_2_no" value="no">
    <label for="q_2_no">No</label>
</div><br>
<p>Can your concept be easily described and understood?</p>
<div id="q_1">
    <input type="radio" name="q[2]" id="q_3_yes" value="yes">
    <label for="q_3_yes">Yes</label>
    <input type="radio" name="q[2]" id="q_3_no" value="no">
    <label for="q_3_no">No</label>
</div><br>
<input type="submit" name="sub_eit" id="sub_eit" value="Submit">
</div>
</form>
```

The PHP code:

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($_POST['q']); ++$i) {
    if($_POST['q'][$i] == 'yes') {
        ++$yes;
    }
}
```

Now $yes contains the number of radio buttons with the value yes. In this case 0-3. Please pay attention to the fact that if no radio button is selected, it will return NULL, not 0.

Comment: Thank you very much @kapparina but ho do i check the exact amount of "yes" the user has chosen?

Comment: You have 3 radio groups, each with yes and no. So $yes contains either 3 if all 3 questions were answered with yes or less.

Or NULL, if all questions where answered with no.

Does this answer your question? :)

Comment: I have tried to write a statement with `if ($yes < 2) {perform a block of codes}`.But this doesn't work.